# is getPerspectiveTransform broken in opencv python2 wrapper?

Tags: python, opencv

Something appears to be afoul with "getPerspectiveTransform" in the python2 wrapper for opencv. For starters, it takes two arguments instead of the expected three.

So instead of the first wrapper's:

```
cv.GetPerspectiveTransform(source,destination,3x3mat)
```

It's now:

```
cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(?,?)
```

If I try to put in two sets of four quad vert coordinates as the arguments like so:

```
cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(first_set_of_corners, second_set_of_corners)
```

it spits out the following error:

```
cv2.error: C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.
cpp:3194: error: (-215) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV
_32F) == 4
```

If the checkVectors shouldn't equal four (hence the "quad" in quadrangle) then I'm not certain what it wants from me. As with everything else in the python2 wrapper this feature is completely undocumented so I don't know if it's broken or, more likely, that I'm doing it wrong. Has anyone here managed to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

cv2.getPerspectiveTransform is not broken anyway.

May be, your points are of not length 4 or they may not be float32 numbers.

Try following :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1original.jpg',0)

src = np.array([[50,50],[450,450],[70,420],[420,70]],np.float32)
dst = np.array([[0,0],[299,299],[0,299],[299,0]],np.float32)

ret = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src,dst)
print ret
```

Result is :

```
[[  8.36097696e-01  -4.51944700e-02  -3.95451613e+01]
 [ -4.51944700e-02   8.36097696e-01  -3.95451613e+01]
 [  6.45161290e-05   6.45161290e-05   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: Yeah, I wound up here from a different error. Would there be any easy way to know that it wanted float32?  Neither the docstring or OpenCV manual page mentioned that it wanted float32 numbers for cv2.getPerspectiveTransform.

Comment: @darkgreen - the check in the error message is for `CV_32F`; cryptic, but it makes sense once you see it

Comment: Thank you, this helped me too. I changed my code to cv2.getPerspectiveTransform( np.float32(points1), np.float32(points2) )